# Is it possible to automate checking an iOS Application?

Tags: ios

Haven't done any iOS programming but was wondering if the following was possible (and if it needs a dedicated device to run on in the foreground then that is fine as well).

Company used to have a website that when there were events available to work on they would be displayed on the site with a "Request" button to select them.  First come first served basis.  Had a Chrome extension that would refresh the site, see if there were any events available, sort them based on some criteria and then select the top one, sleep a few seconds and do the process again.

The company transitioned from the website to an iOS app which provides the same functionality.  Wanted to see if there was a way on an iOS device if I could open the app, check for events and apply sorting/filtering criteria and select then close the app, sleep a few seconds and do it all again in a loop?

I've heard this isn't possible but I have to imagine there is a way to do that.  Anyone have any ideas?  Of course I'd prefer it to run in the background so I could just do it on my phone but if it has to run in the foreground I can dedicate a different device to it.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: You'd have to keep the app open all the time to do this. But, honestly, this doesn't sound like a task well-suited to an iOS app.

Comment: @jnpdx any other way to accomplish the task?

Comment: If it's an application that runs relatively consistently like this, it sounds like it should be on a server somewhere -- not on someone's phone.

Comment: @jnpdx ok but its opening another iOS application which gets installed on a phone so not sure how it would run on a server.  I don't have access to the original iOS app that I'm trying to monitor or else I wouldn't need this code

Comment: Okay -- I'm not clear on how you're communicated with an iOS app that you don't have the code for either.

Comment: @jnpdx thq question is can a 2nd app be built that opens and performs the necessary steps on the 1st app so basically its doing all the things a human would do without the need for a human to sit there repetitively and check for things to be posted

Comment: No — not unless the original app has a ton of features already built in allow control via url scheme or something like that.

Comment: If I'm understanding the problem correctly, you can make an API request when the user opens the app & display the latest results at that time. If you need those results to update in real time, you should set up a socket connection so the app receives updates while open. If the user needs to get background updates, use remote push notifications to notify a user when a new event is available for them.

Comment: @AdamPro13 I don't have access to the original application source code.  What I'm trying to do is build a second application to monitor the first and take action when a new event is available for the user

Comment: In that case, I'd set up a server to be constantly checking that original data source, then have the app connect to your server and do what I described above